# Hibernate Table Per Subclass and NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate

I have several tables mapped in a table-per-subclass manner.

At the top of the hierarchy is EmployeeTransaction, which contains a Composite Primary Key class:

```
public class EmployeeTransaction implements Serializable {

    private TransactionCompositeId id;

    @Id
    public TransactionCompositeId getId() { // etc }}

}

    public static class TransactionCompositeId implements Serializable {

        public String employeeId;
        public Long transactionId;

        // getters/setters
    }
```

So, figure one of the child classes I have is HiringTransaction:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(//etc)
public class HiringTransaction extends EmployeeTransaction implements Serializable {

    // etc
}
```

Now, there are cases were an EmployeeTransaction needs to be created on its own, then not associated with one of the child classes until later.

Here is some code from a Unit Test, which is resulting in a NonUniqueObjectException:

```
@Test
@Rollback(false)
public void testSave()
{
    final TransactionCompositeId id = new TransactionCompositeId("777777777",553942L);

    EmployeeTransaction pt = new EmployeeTransaction();                pt.setId(id);
    pt.setLastUpdate(date);
    pt.setLastUpdatedBy(user);
    pt.setCreatedBy(user);
    pt.setCreationDate(date);
                // various setters

    employeeTransactionDAO.save(pt);


    //EmployeeTransaction pt1 = employeeTransactionDAO.get(id); 

    TransactionCompositeId newId = new TransactionCompositeId("777777777",553942L);
    HiringTransaction eth = new HiringTransaction();            
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(pt, eth);
    //HiringTransaction eth = (HiringTransaction) pt;
    //HiringTransaction eth = new HiringTransaction(pt);
    eth.setId(newId);
                // various setters/getters

    dao.save(eth);


    HiringTransaction tempEth = dao.get(id);
    assertNotNull("HiringTransaction should not be null", tempEth);

    dao.remove(id);
    ptDAO.remove(id);
    tempEth = dao.get(id);
    EmployeeTransaction tempPt = ptDAO.get(id);
    assertNotNull("EmployeeTransaction should not be null", tempEth);
    assertNotNull("HiringTransaction should not be null", tempPt);
}
```

What I suspect is that I can't put both of these activities inside a single UnitOfWork. However, I don't know how to get around the NonUniqueObjectException. The id is definitely the same, since the mapping is table per subclass.

Note: the DAOs are simple Generic DAOs calling session.save(), session.merge(), etc.

Comment: I have a problem to create a hbm file for table per class and composite primary key. Would you please help me to create mapping file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955085/how-to-define-hibernate-mapping-file-with-table-per-subclass-and-composite-id

Comment: I do not use HBM files, only annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to have two different persistent instances of EmployeeTransaction with the same ID. This is not possible. You'll have to delete the EmployeeTransaction, (probably) flush the session, then save the new one with the same ID.

Note that all the associations to the original EmployeeTransaction will have to be deleted as well. If that's not possible, then you shouldn't have an inhertiance relationship, but a composition relationship: One EmployeeTransaction has (zero or) one HiringTransaction.

Comment: Is what I want possible if I change from a Table per Subclass to a Table per Concrete Class hierarchy?

Comment: No. In an entity inheritance tree, you can't have two entities with the same ID. All are instances or the same root entity, and all instances of an entity must have a unique ID.

Comment: Okay, it was worth a shot. Thanks for the help.